# How can I find a question on Stack Exchange?

Tags: support, questions, search

I have read a question a few years back, and it has been answered: 'What would be the last artificial light after apocalypse'

I couldn't find it with tags, and I'm not sure on which site it was asked specifically.

Is there a way to find that question and its answers again?

Comment: Do you know the specific Stack Exchange site? It sounds like the crazy *[Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/tour)* site.

Comment: Site mods can search for deleted posts. However, you need to remember the site the question was posted in the first place.

Comment: If the question was closed and then deleted (you said it was a few years ago) then you've lost all hope of ever finding it again. You need to remember or figure out which one or possibly two sites you saw that question and that answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stack Exchange does have a search box that searches the entire network.  You can find it at https://stackexchange.com/.  However, it's...not great.

Your best bet is most likely to use your favorite search engine, with `site:stackexchange.com` added to your query ([example](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=etymology%20of%20red%20team%20site%25253Astackexchange.com) to find one of my questions using DuckDuckGo).  This will work as long as the question you're looking for isn't on one of the six sites with their own domain name ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Super User](https://superuser.com/), [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/), [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/), [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/), or [Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/)) or their meta sites, which you'll need to search separately (e.g., `site:stackoverflow.com`, etc.).

Comment: For what it's worth, I took a crack at finding this particular question on Google out of curiosity, but I did not succeed in finding it.